# How can I send an object to wcf service?

Tags: jquery, json, wcf

I have a WCF service with a custom class object as paramter.

```
MyClass Call(MyParameter Parameter)
```

I need to pass this object, Parameter, to this service and proceed with the rest of the operations in the service. I need to call this service through JQuery. I tried JSON object but it does not work, I must be doing something wrong if it should work, that is.

**I tried**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:56779/Service.svc/web/Call",
            data: { Parameter: parameter },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            username: "xxxx",
            password: "yyyy",
            processData: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });
```

**with**

```
var parameter = {
            "Parameter": {
                "ID": "A5",
                "Var": "5",
                "Reference": {
                    "ID": "12345678"
                },
                "Order": {
                    "ID": 10,
                    "Category": {
                        "Price": {
                            "Value": "1000"
                        },
                        "Quantity": {
                            "Value": 4
                        },
                        "Date": "1/14/2013"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

I also tried

```
data: JSON.stringify(parameter)
```

but it doesn't work, service is not even called and error occurs. Please let me know how to go about it.

My real task is to send such object as a SOAP message and get a SOAP response; if I don't need to go through JSON, then please guide me directly to achieve my goal.

P.S. I would want to know how to send objects to WCF service, with or without SOAP so, when I'm guided to my goal, I'd be glad to have another guidance regarding this extra goal.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use ASP.NET WebAPI with JQuery http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: this service is being used by a windows application as well, it's a custom username-password authentication service and it needs to be used. is there some other way? WCF service NEEDS to be used!

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice SO question on making a WCF service that accepts Json requests here. I think this will answer your question.

[Http Post Format for WCF Restful Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530169/http-post-format-for-wcf-restful-service)

You need to be sure that your WCF service is configured to expect Json requests. I'd also recommend that you use a tool like [SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org/) to verify that the service's expected request (and response) formats are as you expect.

Comment: I don't need to use RESTful service. My requirement are changed, I'm asked to use HttpWebRequest to consume the service, rather than JQuery AJAX; of course, with HTTP POST request. If you have any suggestions regarding it, I'd be glad to know. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Ok. That sounds like a new question so.